# Unable to parse HTTP packet using netfilter hooks in kernel module

Tags: linux, kernel-modules, firewall, http, netfilter

I am trying to parse HTTP packets using netfilter hooks in my kernel module. I came across this code snippet on [How to print data from TCP packets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29584449/7319413) which I modified to make it build. However, I am unable to see any logs related to `HTTP` in `dmesg` even though I have loaded the kernel module successfully.

I have tried to debug the issue but haven't been able to figure out what's going wrong, the payload is not matching with `HTTP`.I suspect that the problem might be related to the fact that `HTTP` packets are carried over TCP and I am not properly handling the TCP protocol.

Code I am using:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/netfilter.h>
#include <linux/netfilter_ipv4.h>
#include <linux/ip.h>
#include <linux/tcp.h>

#define PTCP_WATCH_PORT 80 /* HTTP port */

static struct nf_hook_ops nfho;

static unsigned int ptcp_hook_func(const struct nf_hook_ops *ops,
                                   struct sk_buff *skb,
                                   const struct net_device *in,
                                   const struct net_device *out,
                                   int (*okfn)(struct sk_buff *))
{
    struct iphdr *iph;        /* IPv4 header */
    struct tcphdr *tcph;      /* TCP header */
    u16 sport, dport;         /* Source and destination ports */
    u32 saddr, daddr;         /* Source and destination addresses */
    unsigned char *user_data; /* TCP data begin pointer */
    unsigned char *tail;      /* TCP data end pointer */
    unsigned char *it;        /* TCP data iterator */

    /* Network packet is empty, seems like some problem occurred. Skip it */
    if (!skb)
        return NF_ACCEPT;

    iph = ip_hdr(skb); /* get IP header */

    /* Skip if it's not TCP packet */
    if (iph->protocol != IPPROTO_TCP)
        return NF_ACCEPT;

    tcph = tcp_hdr(skb); /* get TCP header */

    /* Convert network endianness to host endiannes */
    saddr = ntohl(iph->saddr);
    daddr = ntohl(iph->daddr);
    sport = ntohs(tcph->source);
    dport = ntohs(tcph->dest);

    /* Watch only port of interest */
    if (sport != PTCP_WATCH_PORT)
        return NF_ACCEPT;

    /* Calculate pointers for begin and end of TCP packet data */
    user_data = (unsigned char *)((unsigned char *)tcph + (tcph->doff * 4));
    tail = skb_tail_pointer(skb);

    /* ----- Print all needed information from received TCP packet ------ */

    /* Show only HTTP packets */
    if (user_data[0] != 'H' || user_data[1] != 'T' || user_data[2] != 'T' ||
        user_data[3] != 'P')
    {
        // Control is reaching here always.
        return NF_ACCEPT;
    }

    /* Print packet route */
    printk("print_tcp: %pI4h:%d -> %pI4h:%d\n", &saddr, sport,
           &daddr, dport);

    /* Print TCP packet data (payload) */
    printk("print_tcp: data:\n");
    for (it = user_data; it != tail; ++it)
    {
        char c = *(char *)it;

        if (c == '\0')
            break;

        printk("%c", c);
    }
    printk("\n\n");

    return NF_ACCEPT;
}

static int __init ptcp_init(void)
{
    int res;

    nfho.hook = (nf_hookfn *)ptcp_hook_func; /* hook function */
    nfho.hooknum = NF_INET_PRE_ROUTING;      /* received packets */
    nfho.pf = PF_INET;                       /* IPv4 */
    nfho.priority = NF_IP_PRI_FIRST;         /* max hook priority */

    res = nf_register_net_hook(&init_net,&nfho);
    if (res < 0)
    {
        printk("print_tcp: error in nf_register_hook()\n");
        return res;
    }

    printk("print_tcp: loaded\n");
    return 0;
}

static void __exit ptcp_exit(void)
{
    nf_unregister_net_hook(&init_net,&nfho);
    printk("print_tcp: unloaded\n");
}

module_init(ptcp_init);
module_exit(ptcp_exit);

MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Module for printing HTTP packet data");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Comment: Uh, what happens if I send you a TCP packet < 4 bytes?

Comment: @MarcusMüller, As per my understanding all http packets starts with `http` in the tcp payload.So I added that check but I will add a check before accessing the values.

Comment: 1. "*all http packets starts with http in the tcp payload*" that's wrong. The data payload of the *first* TCP packet of a HTTP interaction starts with "HTTP", all subsequent TCP packets do not (or do, if the data you're sending contains the string "HTTP", which is not that rare).

Comment: 2. not all TCP packets are HTTP packets, and even in HTTP, packets shorter than 4 bytes are possible. So, `your user_data[N]` might just read an address that's not filled with packet data (in case of an empty TCP packet, I'm not even sure `tcph + (tcph->doff * 4)` would point to a valid address – and you might just crash your machine by letting your kernel access an invalid memory address)

Comment: @MarcusMüller, Thanks for the insight, I will add a extra check before checking the header. Is there any otherway to access the payload other than `tcph + (tcph->doff * 4)`, I tried to use `skb->data + eth_hdr_len + ip_hdr_len + tcp_hdr_len` but it seems not working.

Comment: 3. HTTP/1.1. (so, the oldest version of HTTP you will find in the wild), and any later version of HTTP, does offer a [*persistent TCP connection*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) mechanism, where you need to understand the previous HTTP request/reply, including all headers and data that was sent to the server and from the server, to know where the next HTTP request might start. So, prepare for this to become much more complicated later on!

Comment: Re: accessing the data: you're correctly accessing the data (as far as I can tell), it's just that you **always** have to make sure your data is as long as you read data from it, AND that your assumption about *every* HTTP packet starting with "HTTP" is wrong.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, yes, I am new to this network programming and trying to parse any appl protocal so I choose `http`.But It seems to be complicated.

Comment: HTTP/1.0 is probably among the easier protocols, but it's not used anymore. But: have you had a look at the TCP packets of a HTTP connection, for example when capturing one in wireshark? That might be very instructive!

Comment: yes, I can see the HTTP packets in the wireshark and I added an extra check if tcp payload is more than 100 then only parse the data.In wireshark the HTTP packet contains the information about Date,servername,Content-type,... so its length is around 200 most of the times.so I used 100 safer side for small HTTP packets.Do you recommend any other simple protocal for parsing?

Comment: don't do that. A HTTP request doesn't have to be 100 bytes or longer. Don't start making unnecessary assumptions, they only make your life harder. If you need to read the first 4 bytes, check whether the packet is four bytes long or longer! If you want to check whether a TCP *transfer* starts with "HTTP", then check whether you're at the first packet of a TCP connection! Implement HTTP, not something that "shares a couple of keywords with it".

Comment: @MarcusMüller, got it.I will look into the points you mentioned,Thank you.